# how to fix go delve debugger adapter error with docker?

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, delve

I have started a headless instance of the go delve debugger inside a container. The remote server is listening on port `2345`. Then I connected to the server in vscode with this `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "mode": "remote",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remotePath": "/demo",
      "port": 2345,
      "env": {},
      "args": [],
      "showLog": true,
      "trace": "verbose"
    }
  ]
}
```

The docker is working fine. But when I'm keeping break points I'm getting the below error:

```
Unhandled error in debug adapter: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addr')
    at GoDebugSession.convertDebugVariableToProtocolVariable (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/golang.go-0.35.1/dist/debugAdapter.js:16709:25)
    at /Users/user/.vscode/extensions/golang.go-0.35.1/dist/debugAdapter.js:16249:55
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
```

Comment: more details please.  What exactly are you doing to get the error? It looks like the launch.json should also have an addr field

Comment: updated. and may i know what is addr field? couldn't find it on google.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported as <del>[vscode-go#2397](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2397)</del>, and was fixed by [vscode-go#2618](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/pull/2618). The fix has been shipped in `v0.38.0` (28 Feb, 2023).

But according to the comments in the issue report, the root cause is that the application is built with optimization turned on. It's better to compile debugging binaries with `-gcflags="all=-N -l"`. See [dlv exec](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_exec.md#dlv-exec).

BTW, the `addr` field is in the source code of the `vscode-go` extension. See the pull request [vscode-go#2618](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/pull/2618) for more information.